# Specifying horizontal limits in Viewshed 2 tool of ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, 3d-analyst, viewshed

I am using the Viewshed 2 tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8 in a simple Python script. I am trying to calculate individual viewsheds about a series of points, each with horizontal limits of +-30 degrees about north. However, if I specify the start angle as 330 and the completion angle as 30, I get an error stating that the initial angle cannot be greater than the final angle. If I instead use -30 for the initial value, it will only calculate between 0-30 (because values must be between 0 and 360 according to the help file).

I realize I can do this in two passes and then merge the outputs, but surely this possibility must have been envisioned?

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?

Comment: How about 330-390?

Comment: Duh, that's exactly right. Teach me to read help files literally.